# macOS Monterey Bricked - Bluetooth and Wifi crashing

Tags: macos, macos-monterey

I was trying to remove Kaspersky completely from my system (**M1 Macbook Pro macOS 12 Monterey**). I was stuck with one Systemextension "com.kaspersky.kav.sysext" that I could not easily remove. I was lead to [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253775473) forum thread where someone suggested using [FAF (Find Any File)](https://apps.tempel.org/FindAnyFile/index.php) to find the system extension and remove it. I ended up removing all the files associated with kaspersky that FAF showed me and emptied my trash. After restarting the system I noticed my bluetooth was not working and neither did my wifi. Wifi is trying to connect to a network and you can see it loading. Going to System Prefences -> Network nothing is showing up on the left side. After a couple of minutes the system crashes. I suspect that I accidentally deleted a critical system file. What are my options to restore the system?

Answer (score 1):

**Golden Rule:** Never try to pull an antivirus out by hand. By design, they will resist that. Trying to do it on a signed & sealed system volume will just add to your misery.

Next step, reinstall the OS from Recovery. It will not touch your apps or files, just fix the OS.

After that, you might need to install Kaspersky again, then uninstall it **properly** using its uninstaller.
https://support.kaspersky.com/15587

BTW, the method to get to Recovery has changed for the M1 Macs - see https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchl82829c17/mac

Comment: And they are describing this software which is incredibly difficult to remove from your system as an antivirus? Hmm. I tend to find many av software remove harmless files I don't want them to without asking as well... you gotta wonder if the cure is worse than the disease.

Comment: @SwiftD - antiviruses are **supposed** to be hard to kill. That's their **job**.

Comment: In the case of Kaspersky: The German Government (and US as well afaik) released a security warning to not use it. That is why I do not want to use their uninstaller. Especially after trying everything that particular system extension was stubbornly still running and the process could not even be killed which makes me wonder. Anyway, after a reinstall of macOS everything seems to be back in order plus the system extension is gone.

Comment: Political shenanigans aside, AVs are designed to be very hard to kill; otherwise a virus's first job would be to kill it. That in itself is not suspicious. Glad the OS re-install managed to do it for you :)

Comment: Unfortunately after restarting the system, the problem presists. What would be the next thing to try? Do a backup and a clean install? Even when the system is booted to the login screen, it crashes and reboots after 2 mins.

Comment: Pointless backing it up now. If you have an earlier backup, then sure. Otherwise you're gonna have to bite the bullet & uninstall it properly.

Comment: What I can do, is to reinstall the system again first and save all my important data manually, then wipe everything and manually install everything again right?

Comment: You're making this inordinately complicated. Sure, do it that way…. except you already tried to overlay the OS & it failed, so what makes you think doing it a second time will be more successful?

Comment: No but I need to do it to access my files. Maybe another thing that is worth the shot then is to reinstall Kaspersky while the system is usable.

Comment: How many times are you going to do it before you concede it's not working? You could just nuke & pave it… but you also failed to keep a backup. Which is worse, trusting the ruskies or seeing if their uninstaller will get you out of this mess you created for yourself? You did this without research & without a safety net. I really can't help any further.

Comment: I think you missed the point there. I can not use their uninstaller cause the system freezes after 2 minutes of usage, unless I do a reinstall which then the system works until rebooting. So, yeah sure I would use their uninstaller if I could.